# Resize Disk Partition on Remote VM Server

Tags: server, partitioning, virtualization

I'm running Ubuntu Server 10.04 on a remote server as a VM. I only have access to the VM.

The VM is assign a disk space of 20GB, however the drive is currently only partitioned to use about 4.7GB.

I know that you can use LiveCD to repartition a drive using gparted. How would you go about doing that on a remote VM? (Since the partition is also the startup volume)

```
# fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 21.5 GB, 21474836480 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 2610 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00074164

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *           1         618     4959232   83  Linux
Partition 1 does not end on cylinder boundary.
/dev/sda2             618         653      280577    5  Extended
Partition 2 does not end on cylinder boundary.
/dev/sda5             618         653      280576   82  Linux swap / Solaris
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That what I would try:

1. Many VPS hosting providers have tools to manipulate partitions in their control panels. Getting access to the control panel would be the safest option.
2. Do not resize the partition but create a second partition and move your "working" data to that partition. I'e. mount `/home` or wherever your data is to a separate partition
3. If you still feel adventurous, try remounting the boot partition read-only and see if it's possible to resize it while mounted read-only
4. Something really tricky like remove swap - create a copy of your root partition at the very end of the drive - configure grub to boot from the new partition - reboot - resize your original partition - copy the data back - modify grub again - reboot - remove the temporary root partition - create a swap partition again.

I would consider the second two options really dangerous in the sense that if anything goes wrong your system just won't boot so you'd lose any access to the system.

Comment: Although both answers are excellent. I choose this as the accepted solution since essentially #1 is what we ended up with. (IT fixed)

Comment: I've tried the last option but lost the access to the machine because I didn't configured ssh in that other partition

Answer (score 16):

### If you want to enlarge the system partition

First, turn off swap (`swapoff /dev/sda5`), because we'll temporarily remove the swap partition.

Use GParted or `cfdisk` or `fdisk` to:

1. Remove the logical partition `/dev/sda5` and the extended partition `/dev/sda2`.
2. Enlarge `/dev/sda1` to span the whole disk minus what you want to allocate for the swap partition.
3. Re-create a partition (make it a primary partition for simplicity) for the swap.

Do not turn swap back on. Comment out the swap line in `/etc/fstab`, and **reboot**. (If you don't reboot, the kernel keeps using obsolete data about the partitioning, which can have disastrous consequences.)

After the reboot, edit `/etc/fstab` to change the name of the swap device and uncomment it. Format the swap area with `mkswap` and activate it with `swapon -a`.

Finally enlarge the existing filesystem to occupy all of `/dev/sda1` with `resize2fs /dev/sda1`.

### If you want to create another partition

Use GParted to enlarge the extended partition (`/dev/sda2`) and create a new logical partition `/dev/sda6` on it. Tell GParted that you'll want a Linux filesystem on `/dev/sda6`. Create a filesystem with `mke2fs -t ext4 /dev/sda6`.

Comment: but but but... you can't resize a partition which is currenly mounted - that would have really disastrous consequences. That's the whole point - if booted from a partition you can't resize it.

Comment: Although our IT department was able to solve it (they have the control panel and I believe unmounted the partition and resized it), your answer, although dangerous, is a good option if I had to do it myself. +1

Comment: @Sergey You can enlarge a mounted partition, and that's in fact pretty safe. You can even shrink or move a mounted partition, because the kernel doesn't read the updated information; what would be disastrous would be to do anything on the partition afterwards, like create a filesystem on it.

Comment: I have serious doubts... Do you have any links to support this? Note that we're talking about the partition we just booted from, i.e. it already have a filesystem on it. How do you ensure that no processes use the partition while you're resizing it? That would only work in a single-task OS such as MS-DOS

Comment: @Sergey It's vitally important that no process use the partition. But that's ok: in normal operation, no process uses the partition. It's just fine if a process continues to access an already-mounted filesystem, because the filesystem driver never updates its knowledge about the partition, it keeps using the old boundaries from mount time. Source: my experience, and browsing the kernel sources.

Answer (score 1):

If you're running a cloud machine (in my case it runs a custom Kali image with just 16GB of the disk), and the only access to it is through `ssh`, then this answer is for you.

So **without needing to remount** the partition, following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60543181/12096922) can make it work. In the case you need to remove some intermediate partitions, do so before proceeding to the following step.

> 1. Increase disk size from console first
> 2. SSH inside VM : sudo growpart /dev/sda 1
> 3. Resize your file system : sudo resize2fs /dev/sda1
> 4. Verify : df -h

Answer (score 0):

Excuse me! I just read your question, let me help you!

Size(VM usable memory) == Size(main partitions) + Size(extended partitions);

Size(extended partition) == Size(logical partition)s;

Size(VM disk memory) == Size(VM usable memory) + Size(free space);

So, if you want to use the free space on your VM's disk space, you need to expand the `/dev/sda1`, and there are no other partitions between the main partition `/dev/sda1` and the free space.

Just use `sudo fdisk -l` to check your partition's usage, I guess your output just liking below:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 21.5 GB, 21474836480 bytes, 62914560 sectors
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 2610 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00074164

Device     Boot    Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *        512M     5.2G  4902880  4.7G 83 Linux
/dev/sda2           5.2G     6.2G   580000    1G  5 Extended
/dev/sda5           5.2G     6.2G   580000    1G 82 Linux swap / Solaris
```

And after your main partition or usable partition up to `20GB`, your new `sudo fdisk -l`:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 21.5 GB, 21474836480 bytes, 62914560 sectors
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 2610 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00074164

Device     Boot    Start      End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *       512M     20.5G  42162880    20G 83 Linux
/dev/sda2          20.5G    21.5G    580000     1G  5 Extended
/dev/sda5          20.5G    21.5G    580000     1G 82 Linux swap / Solaris
```

Solution:

0.Just log in your VM's terminal;

1.turn off your `swap` permission: `sudo swapoff /dev/sda5`;

And use command `free -h` to check whether swapoff do matter or not, if you see the free or total space percent of swap partition is `0B`, that means successfully turn off the swap.

Others, reboot, or restart will automatically turn on the swap, using command `sudo swapoff swap_partition_directory` just temporarily turn off swap.

2.Remove extended partition `/dev/sda2` and logical/swap partition `/dev/sda5`:

First remove logical/swap partition `/dev/sda5`, then extended partition `/dev/sda2`;

Just use `cfdisk` to do the upstairs job, using `sudo cfdisk` to enter the power of `cfdisk`.

Using `up` and `down` direction button to choose the partition, using `right` and `left` direction button to choose the operation, uisng `enter` button to make sure.

Choose `Delete` button to remove logical/swap partition `/dev/sda5` and extended partition `/dev/sda2`.

3.Resize the main partition:

Also, using `cfdisk`, just use `Resize` button to do that, change resized size from default `21GB` into `20GB`;

4.Re-create extended partition `/dev/sda2` and logical/swap partition `/dev/sda5`:

Also, using `cfdisk`, use `New` button to create extended partition `/dev/sda2` on the free space, then create logical partition `/dev/sda5`, both of them use default size `1 GB`;

Now, select `Quit` button to quit `cfdisk`.

5.Set your logical partition `/dev/sda5`'s file type: `sudo mkswap /dev/sda5`;

Update your new logical/swap partition `/dev/sda5`'s `UUID`, use `lsblk -f | grep "swap"` to check swap partition's `UUID`, copy that, and change the `UUID` of swap in `/etc/fstab` via `sudo vim /etc/fstab`, using `i` button to edit, copy your new swap `UUID` instead of the old `UUID` of the former swap.

6.Set all the file types of main partition `/dev/sda1`: `sudo resize2fs /dev/sda1`.

7.Restart or reboot your virtual machine: `sudo reboot`.

Have fun!!!:)

OVER!