# Increase partition size on which Ubuntu is installed?

Tags: disk

I have Ubuntu installed on a drive. The problem is it is running low on disk space. This is installed on vmware. I expanded the virtual drive and booted into ubuntu. But when I opened gparted(sudo gparted), the move/resize option is unavailable. This is the partition Ubuntu is installed on, but I need to resize it. Any ideas? I am comfortable using command line

Comment: You can see how they do it in `raspi-config` for the Raspberry Pi, where expanding the root file system is something you do almost every time you set up a new Raspberry Pi. https://github.com/RPi-Distro/raspi-config/blob/9895c6cfc897339887a471b8ee891d606c3ed79b/raspi-config#L116

Comment: I've found a youtube tutorial which can be a good answer for this question, it starts at this position: https://youtu.be/07hpUigWQyY?t=1538

Comment: I do highly recommend you use `cfdisk` or `gdisk` to resize your partition on VMware VM.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

EDIT: *As mentioned below by @kent this is an old answer and no longer true.*

You are almost there.
You **can not** resize the partition using GParted while Ubuntu is running.
You will need to attach the GParted ISO's as a CD to the VM machine and reboot the machine so that the GParted will be loaded instead of Ubuntu (I think you can boot from the virtual CD by pressing F12 immediately after machine is started).
Once you booted into GParted the option to move/resize will be enabled as Ubuntu is not currently running.

Comment: It should be noted that this answer is no longer correct.  You *can* run gparted from a terminal in Gnome desktop.  I have done this trivially with Ubuntu 18 & 20.  In my case I had to first extend the "extended" partition, then I extended the nested ext4 partition within the previous partition.  I don't know if it is required, but I did this in 2 separate operations rebooting after each.  Also, after each extension in gparted be sure to click the checkmark on the button bar to save the changes.  I added 15GB to my primary in under 2 minutes with no special mounting of ISOs.

Answer (score 245):

As a matter of fact, you **CAN** *enlarge* the root filesystem while Ubuntu is running (I learned this recently myself [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/109224/14564)) - this sounds incredible but it's true :)

Here's the list of steps for a simple scenario where you have two partitions, `/dev/sda1` is an ext4 partition the OS is booted from and `/dev/sdb2` is swap. For this exercise we want to remove the swap partition an extend `/dev/sda1` to the whole disk.

1. As always, make sure you have a backup of your data - since we're going to modify the partition table there's a chance to lose all your data if you make a typo, for example.
2. Run `sudo fdisk /dev/sda`

   - use `p` to list the partitions. Make note of the start cylinder of `/dev/sda1`
   - use `d` to **delete** first the swap partition (`2`) and then the `/dev/sda1` partition. This is very scary but is actually harmless as the data is not written to the disk until you write the changes to the disk.
   - use `n` to **create** a new primary partition. Make sure its start cylinder is exactly the same as the old `/dev/sda1` used to have. For the end cylinder agree with the default choice, which is to make the partition to span the whole disk.
   - use `a` to toggle the bootable flag on the new `/dev/sda1`
   - review your changes, make a deep breath and use `w` to write the new partition table to disk. You'll get a message telling that the kernel couldn't re-read the partition table because the device is busy, but that's ok.
3. Reboot with `sudo reboot`. When the system boots, you'll have a smaller *filesystem* living inside a larger *partition*.
4. The next magic command is `resize2fs`. Run `sudo resize2fs /dev/sda1` - this form will default to making the filesystem to take all available space on the partition.

That's it, we've just resized a partition on which Ubuntu is installed, without booting from an external drive.

Comment: @EliahKagan: Please have a look at the answer (from Gilles) I linked to. The idea is that it is possible to use `fdisk` to enlarge the _partition_, while the OS continues to use the smaller filesystem. Then. after a reboot, after kernel re-reads the updated partition table, we can resize the _filesystem_ because it now lives in a larger partition.

Comment: @EliahKagan: ok, you're right, I need to try it myself :) Let's see if I have a spare HDD to play with...

Comment: @EliahKagan: Ok, I've tried Gilles's "recipe" and it does indeed work nicely. I've revised my answer with a detailed list of steps to enlarge a "live" partition without booting from an external medium. You may remove your downvote now ;)

Comment: @Sergey Is that also possible if the free space is _before_ the partition to enlarge? I know the start point of the partition is important, but might it be possible to work around that? Maybe by moving/copying the first n Bytes of the partition to the new left border?

Comment: @ByteCommander: No, it would only work in one very specific case when the filesystem is enlarged (not shrunk) and when the free space is at the end of the filesystem. For all other scenarios you need to take the partition offline. The easiest would be to use GParted in this case, but in theory you can do everything using command-line tools if you want.

Comment: So ultimately, we still have to reboot to get a larger root partition?

Comment: @Isaac: Yes, we still have to reboot to make the kernel to re-read the partition table. However, a quick reboot in many scenarios is a much smaller problem than booting from an external medium (think of remote machines, headless machines, VPSes etc.)

Comment: I tried many different answers on SO but none of them worked. However, this answer did the job for me. Thanks! I'm running Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS.

Comment: I had to use `resize2fs /dev/sda1` afterwards to get the additional space in the partition.

Comment: `Value out of range.` when trying to select `/dev/sda1` start cylinder.

Comment: Two quick notes: 1. You can use `df` to show the "resulting" space after this (confirm that it worked), and 2. remember to recreate some swap space!

Comment: Thanks so much. Ubuntu never used the space I gave the VirtualBox vdisk. Now I know why. Many thanks!

Comment: Thanks for a great post. In step 2, after running 'n', it prompts whether to delete a signature. I choose to retain the signature, and approach works as expected.

Comment: The start cylinder same as last the initial is creating a bit of a problem for me. The unallocated space is before the boot drive. So if I keep the first sector same the space doesn't get occupied.

Comment: @Sid: It is very important that the start cylinder is the exactly the same. If the free space is anywhere but immediately after the partition you need to use another method (which would require booting from another drive)

Comment: @Sergey Thanks. I am creating the live usb for it now. :)

Comment: what's wrong with https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/recognize-expanded-volume-linux.html ?

Comment: That's exactly how `raspi-config` does it on a Raspberry Pi. This works!

Comment: if you happen to be using an LVM (ie: df -h shows that / is mounted at /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv ) then far quicker to follow the simple steps at "Resizing Partitions" in the official ubuntu page: "https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Lvm"

Comment: It erases all of my data!!!

Comment: @Lobster: The steps above can't erase all your data because the very first step is to make sure you have a backup of your data. Any modification of partitions is dangerous and has a potential for data loss, so it's really important you have a backup.

Comment: I should note that it gave me a prompt "Do you want to remove the ext4 signature" on /dev/sda1 and I said no and it worked perfectly.

Comment: How to get swap partition back ? This is not explained ? Will linux ubuntu work without a swap partition, this would actually be nice... swap partition is like pagefile.sys right ? an out-dated concept.

Comment: Ubuntu will totally work without a swap partition, yes - if you have enough RAM. It is often advisable to have a swap partition though (not sure why you think it's an outdated concept). 

You can create a swap partition in the remaining unpartitioned space, if you have any, or create a swap file in one of your partitions, or do not have a swap.

Comment: "a: unknown command". It is apparently a captital A

Comment: "w: unknown command", this happened because I'm in expert mode.

Comment: This is exactly the kind of answer I was looking for

Comment: This guide worked for me: https://packetpushers.net/ubuntu-extend-your-default-lvm-space/    It does `lvextend -l +100%FREE /dev/ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv` and then `resize2fs /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv`

Answer (score 98):

## Two Methods

### **1. Tested in Ubuntu Server 16.04 to 18.10**

After extending the volume in VMware ESXi (shutdown vm, backup/export vm, remove all snapshots, then increased number in disk size, take snapshot of vm again before following the next steps so you can revert mistake/error).

The following example is extending volume on root partition on a system that is already using LVM.

1. `ssh` into the system, switch to root and run `cfdisk`
    # cfdisk
2. [image]
3. [image]
4. [image]
5. [image]
6. [image]
7. [image]
8. [image]
9. [image]
10. [image]
11. [image]
12. [image]
13. After exiting cfdisk

    ```
     # fdisk -l /dev/sda 
     Disk /dev/sda: 20 GiB, 21474836480 bytes, 41943040 sectors
     Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
     Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
     I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
     Disklabel type: dos
     Disk identifier: 0xc8b647ff

     Device     Boot    Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
     /dev/sda1  *        2048   999423   997376  487M 83 Linux
     /dev/sda2        1001470 16775167 15773698  7.5G  5 Extended
     /dev/sda3       16775168 41943039 25167872   12G 8e Linux LVM (***** See new partition /dev/sda3*****)
     /dev/sda5        1001472 16775167 15773696  7.5G 8e Linux LVM
    ```
14. Reboot system before next step (or else you might get `Device
     /dev/sda3 not found (or ignored by filtering)`)

    ```
     # shutdown now -r
    ```
15. Initialize the new volume

    ```
     # pvcreate /dev/sda3
       Physical volume "/dev/sda3" successfully created
    ```
16. Get the name of volume to extend

    ```
     # vgdisplay
       --- Volume group ---
       VG Name               linuxetc1-vg (***** this is vg i'm extending*****)
       System ID             
       Format                lvm2
       Metadata Areas        1
       Metadata Sequence No  3
       VG Access             read/write
       VG Status             resizable
       MAX LV                0
       Cur LV                2
       Open LV               2
       Max PV                0
       Cur PV                1
       Act PV                1
       VG Size               7.52 GiB
       PE Size               4.00 MiB
       Total PE              1925
       Alloc PE / Size       1925 / 7.52 GiB
       Free  PE / Size       0 / 0  
       ...
    ```
17. Extend volume group

    ```
     # vgextend linuxetc1-vg /dev/sda3
       Volume group "linuxetc1-vg" successfully extended
    ```
18. Extend root

    ```
     # lvextend -l+100%FREE /dev/linuxetc1-vg/root
       Size of logical volume linuxetc1-vg/root changed from 6.52 GiB (1669 extents) to 18.52 GiB (4741 extents).
       Logical volume root successfully resized.


     Or if you only wanted to give 5 more GB to root
     # lvextend -L +5g /dev/linuxetc1-vg/root
    ```
19. Get filesystem name for next step

    ```
     # df -h
     Filesystem                      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
     udev                            477M     0  477M   0% /dev
     tmpfs                           100M  4.6M   95M   5% /run
     /dev/mapper/linuxetc1--vg-root  6.3G  2.5G  3.5G  42% /            (***** this line*****)
     tmpfs                           497M     0  497M   0% /dev/shm
     tmpfs                           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
     tmpfs                           497M     0  497M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
     /dev/sda1                       472M  105M  343M  24% /boot
     tmpfs                           100M     0  100M   0% /run/user/1000
    ```
20. Extend filesystem

    ```
     # resize2fs /dev/mapper/linuxetc1--vg-root
     resize2fs 1.42.13 (17-May-2015)
     Filesystem at /dev/mapper/linuxetc1--vg-root is mounted on /; on-line resizing required
     old_desc_blocks = 1, new_desc_blocks = 2
     The filesystem on /dev/mapper/linuxetc1--vg-root is now 4854784 (4k) blocks long.
    ```
21. See the increased size

    ```
     # df -h
     Filesystem                      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
     udev                            477M     0  477M   0% /dev
     tmpfs                           100M  4.6M   95M   5% /run
     /dev/mapper/linuxetc1--vg-root   19G  2.5G   15G  15% /         (***** this line*****)
     tmpfs                           497M     0  497M   0% /dev/shm
     tmpfs                           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
     tmpfs                           497M     0  497M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
     /dev/sda1                       472M  105M  343M  24% /boot
     tmpfs                           100M     0  100M   0% /run/user/1000
    ```

### **2. Faster Method Tested in Ubuntu Server 18.04.3 LTS**

This method is a little faster than the first. This is due to a new option in the `cfdisk` menu called *"Resize"* that saves some steps.

After extending the volume in VMware ESXi (shutdown vm, backup/export vm, remove all snapshots, then increased number in disk size, take snapshot of vm again before following the next steps so you can revert mistake/error).

The following example is extending volume on root partition on a system that is already using LVM.

1. `ssh` into the system, switch to root and run `cfdisk`.
2. Choose the partition to extend and select "Resize".
   [image]
3. Set the "New size".
   [image]
4. After pressing enter, you'll see screen with the following note "Partition [someNumber] resized":
   [image]
5. Next you'll need to "Write" (save) your changes:
   [image]
   [image]
   [image]
6. Quit `cfdisk`. When you exit you may see message "syncing disks".
   [image]
   [image]
7. I rebooted my system at this point but it may not be necessary. Now you can pickup from step 19 from the first method (repeated below).
8. (19) Get filesystem name for next step

   ```
    # df -h
    Filesystem                      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
    udev                            477M     0  477M   0% /dev
    tmpfs                           100M  4.6M   95M   5% /run
    /dev/mapper/linuxetc1--vg-root  6.3G  2.5G  3.5G  42% /            (***** this line*****)
    tmpfs                           497M     0  497M   0% /dev/shm
    tmpfs                           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
    tmpfs                           497M     0  497M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
    /dev/sda1                       472M  105M  343M  24% /boot
    tmpfs                           100M     0  100M   0% /run/user/1000
   ```
9. (20) Extend filesystem

   ```
    # resize2fs /dev/mapper/linuxetc1--vg-root
    resize2fs 1.42.13 (17-May-2015)
    Filesystem at /dev/mapper/linuxetc1--vg-root is mounted on /; on-line resizing required
    old_desc_blocks = 1, new_desc_blocks = 2
    The filesystem on /dev/mapper/linuxetc1--vg-root is now 4854784 (4k) blocks long.
   ```
10. (21) See the increased size

    ```
     # df -h
     Filesystem                      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
     udev                            477M     0  477M   0% /dev
     tmpfs                           100M  4.6M   95M   5% /run
     /dev/mapper/linuxetc1--vg-root   19G  2.5G   15G  15% /         (***** this line*****)
     tmpfs                           497M     0  497M   0% /dev/shm
     tmpfs                           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
     tmpfs                           497M     0  497M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
     /dev/sda1                       472M  105M  343M  24% /boot
     tmpfs                           100M     0  100M   0% /run/user/1000
    ```

Articles:
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Lvm
http://www.geoffstratton.com/expand-hard-disk-ubuntu-lvm

Comment: Worked perfectly on 18.10 running under ESXi.  Thanks!

Comment: Great guide! Followed this to expand the storage on Ubuntu running as Proxmox VM.

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you for this. This worked for 18.04 running on ESXi.

Comment: Only 1 worked for me, 2 didn't work when resizing (Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS).

Comment: The "Faster" method should be first since it works great on 18.04 and 16.04 is quite outdated already

Comment: On Ubuntu 18.04 didn't work for me as well. I had to do `resize2fs /dev/sdaX`, and that worked thankfully! Don't blame me if you loose data though! :)

Comment: Method 2.Worked perfectly on 20.04 running under Proxmox

Comment: Method 2 should be listed first.

Comment: Most of the faster method worked for me, however,I also had to run `sudo lvextend -l +100%FREE /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root` before running `sudo resize2fs /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root` [this guide helped me figure that out](https://computingforgeeks.com/extending-root-filesystem-using-lvm-linux/)

Comment: Method 2 help me. Should be listed first.
I'm using the 18.04 and my Volume Group was empty. So I try the second method and it worked perfectly. Thanks

Comment: `Failed to resize partition #5.` (nothing more said)

Comment: Method 2 also worked for me (18.04 LTS).  But cfdisk did not show the correct free space and I noticed when I closed it I was getting an error saying "PMBR size mismatch (....) will be corrected by w(rite)".  I ran "parted -l" which detected the issue and repaired it.  All was smooth after that.

Comment: Method 2 worked perfectly for me (Using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS). But you need to follow the instructions properly, and not just copy-paste commands word-for-word. (Especially steps 8-9) (Obviously you also need to `sudo` everything.)

Comment: Worked on Ubuntu 22.04 using Method 1

Comment: In Ubuntu 20.04, for me, it appears to have sensed the volume change and expanded the root file system automagically on reboot - go team!

Comment: The second method did not work for me. I received the same error as @gies0r above (`Failed to resize partition #5`). Ended up using method 1 and everything worked correctly! Cheers!

Comment: This is the best answer. I just now tried it using the "Faster method..." and it worked.

Answer (score 13):

jtlindsey's "faster" method works on LVMs but is missing some steps. `df -h` wouldn't show the additional space.

1. Follow up until step 9.
2. Run `sudo lsblk` to determine your partition name (mine was sda3).
3. Run `sudo pvresize /dev/sda3`
4. Run `sudo lvextend -L +76G /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv` (replacing the size and the name with your own)
5. Go back to his method and finish remaining steps.

Source: https://askubuntu.com/a/1047512/393368

Comment: Thank you. Adding these commands made jtlindsey's "faster" work for me on  Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS

Comment: Many thanks - adding these steps allowed me to use jtlindsey's "faster" method on 22.04.3 LTS

Answer (score 7):

I noticed that my ubuntu VM had a LVM that simply was not using all the allocated space.
So to add space to my LVM it was quite simply this: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Lvm chapter: "resizing partitions".

For example: A quick way to know if you have an LVM is to do `df -h`
and look for this line:

```
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv  689G   20G  639G   3% /
```

And... see that is not actually the classic "/dev/sda1" type of mount point.

Then run the extension commands on that partition.

```
sudo lvextend -L +500g /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv
sudo resize2fs /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv
```

Another quick clue that reminded me to check for an LVM was that I noticed when I looked at the fdisk partitions and saw that I had a large /dev/sda3 partition that was not really mounted  anywhere. (ie: when I checked with the mount command).

Answer (score 3):

With `cfdisk` and `resize2fs` I was able to extend my `/` partition on proxmox VM. Thanks to jtlindsey for the example.

I had the next picture before extending:

```
Model: QEMU QEMU HARDDISK (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 107GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: linux
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    Type      File system     Flags
 1      1049kB  40,0GB  40,0GB  primary   ext4            boot
 2      40,0GB  53,7GB  13,7GB  extended
 5      40,0GB  53,7GB  13,7GB  logical   linux-swap(v1)
```

With `cfdisk` I've removed swap partition, then resized my `/` partition with **Resize** option to 80Gb and recreated the swap partition. Then I've written changes with **Write** option:

```
    Device               Boot                         Start                 End             Sectors          Size          Id Type
>>  /dev/sda1            *                             2048           167774207           167772160           80G          83 Linux                        
    /dev/sda2                                     167774208           209715199            41940992           20G          82 Linux swap / Solaris


┌───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│Partition type: Linux swap / Solaris (82)                                                                                                              │
└───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
                              [Bootable]  [ Delete ]  [ Resize ]  [  Quit  ]  [  Type  ]  [  Help  ]  [  Write ]  [  Dump  ]
```

After this I've rebooted and used the following command to extend my file system to the current partition's size:

```
$ sudo resize2fs /dev/sda1
```

Make sure you've created backup of important data before any disk changing action. So, jtlindsey's method could be used even for none-LVM partitions.

Also do not forget to get swap back by:

```
$ sudo mkswap /dev/sda2
```

And change UUID of swap partition in `/etc/fstab` to what `sudo blkid` shows for it.

Answer (score 2):

The answer from Sergey was excellent. If you have the empty space not directly in the next device, however, you will need to delete other devices. For example:

```
Device     Boot    Start       End  Sectors Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *        2048  33556477 33554430  16G 83 Linux
/dev/sda2       33556478  41940991  8384514   4G  5 Extended
/dev/sda3       41940992 125829119 83888128  40G 83 Linux
/dev/sda5       33556480  41940991  8384512   4G 82 Linux swap / Solaris
```

In the above case, if you want to merge `/dev/sda3` with `/dev/sda1`, you would need to remove `/dev/sda1`, `/dev/sda2`, and `/dev/sda3` (with `d` command), and re-add `/dev/sda2` and update its type (with `n` and `t` commands).

Answer (score 0):

I succeeded in enlarging my primary ext4 partition using the methodology described [here](http://www.howtoforge.com/linux_resizing_ext3_partitions).

Some notes from my personal experience:

- The link example is for shrinking partition, hence the order is resize2fs first and then fdisk. When enlarging partition (as in my case) the order should be fdisk first, reboot and then resize2fs. Also, when using fdisk, the primary as well as the  extended partitions should be removed and re-defined.
- I booted the Ubuntu from another drive and then worked on this drive which actually was mirror (using dd) of the older drive. Made it bootable using GParted
- The current version of resize2fs (I am using Ubuntu 12.04LTS) support ext4 - no need to do the actions described in the link of changing it the ext2.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.