# Ubuntu Server really slow after expanding Hard disk

Tags: 16.04, hard-drive, webserver

Afternoon all,

I expanded our virtual ubuntu server as they ran out of space. Now the machine is running like a dog.

According to the fdisk -l 
i get this:

```
sudo fdisk -l
Disk /dev/sda: 80 GiB, 85899345920 bytes, 167772160 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x12f1824d

Device     Boot    Start       End  Sectors Size Id Type
/dev/sda1           2048  92278781 92276734  44G 83 Linux
/dev/sda2       92278782 104855551 12576770   6G  5 Extended
/dev/sda5       92278784 104855551 12576768   6G 82 Linux swap / Solaris

Partition 2 does not start on physical sector boundary.
```

I'm guessing the drive has not updated it should be 80gb not 44g.

Comment: Probably the expansion process did not go flawless. Unfortunately you forgot to show us what steps you took. Please show us in detail, add it to your question.

Comment: There is some discrepancy between your headline and the (suggested) question at the end. For the size of the disk: `fdisk -l` clearly says the disk is 80 GiB (see the first line), so this is OK. To expand /dev/sda2, you first have to move sda2 to the end of the disk, then increase sda1 and the filesystem it contains. This can all be done via `gparted`.

Comment: Do you know how to do this? @ridgy

Comment: @stoneseraphim you should try gparted you'll be easily be able to do it. Though note-adding the disk size and expanding partitions are two different tasks and later will take more time on basis of the data size that needs to be moved

Comment: I used this https://askubuntu.com/questions/116351/increase-partition-size-on-which-ubuntu-is-installed/116367

Comment: Ah! done it i didn't remove the sda2 partition. Thats been done now and it's working like a charm. the speed of the server is back to normal too.