# How to resize partition via command line?

Tags: command-line, partitioning, resize

I have Ubuntu installed on a VirtualBox VM.
How can I resize the Linux partition (not the virtual drive)?

I already performed the VM resize using VBoxManage modifyhd to resize the virtual drive, but I need to resize the Linux partition.  I do not have a GUI to gparted, so I need to resize the partition from the command line.

Answer (score 5):

**If you use LVM ([Logical Volume Manager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_Volume_Manager_(Linux))):**

1. Expand physical volume (*sda3* replace by your partition name):

   ```
   sudo pvresize /dev/sda3
   ```
2. Check free space:

   ```
   sudo vgdisplay
   ```
3. Add space to logical volume (*VG00/share* replace by your LV path; you can get it from `sudo lvdisplay`):

   ```
   sudo lvresize –L -r 100G VG00/share
   ```
4. Check changes:

   ```
   sudo lvdisplay
   ```

**If you don't use LVM:**

All below commands work for unmounted partition, so you should boot from another source, for example, from *iso* (liveCD image).

1. Change partition size: `sudo fdisk /dev/sda3`:

   - remove old partition (`d`)
   - create new one, bigger (`n`)
   - write changes (`w`)
2. Expand file system:

   ```
   sudo e2fsck -f /dev/sda3
   sudo resize2fs /dev/sda3
   ```
3. Reboot system, boot as usual.
4. Check partitions:

   ```
   df
   ```