# How to move disk space from /home to / (root)

Tags: server, partitioning, 18.04, disk-usage

Can somebody help me move 1.7T of disk space from `/home` to `/`. The disk is on a dedicated server accessed remotely.

`df` command output:

```
Filesystem      1K-blocks    Used  Available Use% Mounted on
udev              8131140       0    8131140   0% /dev
tmpfs             1632332     708    1631624   1% /run
/dev/sda2        20026236 1694544   17291360   9% /
tmpfs             8161648       0    8161648   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                5120       0       5120   0% /run/lock
tmpfs             8161648       0    8161648   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1          498532   80794     387479  18% /boot
/dev/sda3      1857690664   69260 1763233540   1% /home
tmpfs             1632328       0    1632328   0% /run/user/0
```

`lsblk` output:

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0  1.8T  0 disk
├─sda1   8:1    0  511M  0 part /boot
├─sda2   8:2    0 19.5G  0 part /
├─sda3   8:3    0  1.8T  0 part /home
└─sda4   8:4    0  511M  0 part [SWAP]
```

`fdisk -l` output:

```
Device     Boot      Start        End    Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *          4096    1050623    1046528  511M 83 Linux
/dev/sda2          1050624   42008575   40957952 19.5G 83 Linux
/dev/sda3         42008576 3905972223 3863963648  1.8T 83 Linux
/dev/sda4       3905972224 3907018751    1046528  511M 82 Linux swap / Solaris
```

Comment: Welcome to [ubuntu.se]! What have you tried so far? Do you want to move data or change the size of partitions? In the latter case, please [edit] your question to add the output of the `lsblk` command. You could also replace the output of `df` with `df -h` which is more readable.

Comment: Make use of your installation media (DVD, USB). Boot the installer, choose `Try Ubuntu`, then run Gparted and edit the partitions to fit your needs.

Comment: @mook765 Hello mook765, 
This is a dedicated server from OVH reseller I don't have physical access.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to resize partitions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126153/how-to-resize-partitions)

Comment: or https://askubuntu.com/questions/116351/increase-partition-size-on-which-ubuntu-is-installed/116367#116367

Comment: why is / full? if it is due to a mysql database why not move that database to /home/  and edit the config to point to the new location? Should be easier :) Same for apache. You could move it to home and symlink from /var/www/.

Comment: **@RoVo and close voters:** None of the current answers to the duplicate target offers a command-line solution.