# /dev/mapper/lv-root does not exist - after resizing

Tags: boot, partitioning, root

I have ubuntu 16.04 installed on VMware player.
after following this guide: 
[Increase partition size on which Ubuntu is installed?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/116351/increase-partition-size-on-which-ubuntu-is-installed)

third answer, in short i did this steps: 
1. go to vmplayer to machine, extend disk from 40 to 100.
2. started machine - entered terminal and fdisk /dev/sda: 
had 2 sda there /dev/sda1 and /dev/sda2 ( which had 92gib so i assum it was the new added gb)
3. pressed d to delete partition number 2 and then d again ( as followed the answer in guide)
4. then made new partition using n , primary , start cylinder  like the old one and end as default)
5. press a and then w
reboot and nothing works.

errors:
ALERT! /dev/mapper/lv_root does not exist! Dropping to a shell!
Now im in initramfs , safe mood \ old kernal goes back to initramfs

any chance to fix what i did ?