# Low disk Space in Root Filesystem Error - ubuntu 20.04

Tags: partitioning, 20.04

As a developer, I need several applications to be installed. But still never thought it would require more than 15gb space. I constantly getting this warning of Low disk space tried several methods told here [Root drive is running out of disk space. How can I free up space?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/57994/root-drive-is-running-out-of-disk-space-how-can-i-free-up-space/1161181#1161181)
What should I do now?

`df-h` give me this

```
<pre>Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs           787M  2.3M  784M   1% /run
/dev/sda7        15G   13G  483M  97% /    <---------here is the problem
tmpfs           3.9G  309M  3.6G   8% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop0      9.2M  9.2M     0 100% /snap/canonical-livepatch/95
/dev/loop1       98M   98M     0 100% /snap/core/9289
/dev/loop2       94M   94M     0 100% /snap/core/9066
/dev/loop3       55M   55M     0 100% /snap/core18/1705
/dev/loop4       55M   55M     0 100% /snap/core18/1754
/dev/loop5      161M  161M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/116
/dev/loop6      162M  162M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/128
/dev/loop7      256M  256M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/36
/dev/loop8      2.3M  2.3M     0 100% /snap/gnome-system-monitor/145
/dev/loop10     2.3M  2.3M     0 100% /snap/gnome-system-monitor/148
/dev/loop9      256M  256M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/33
/dev/loop11      55M   55M     0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1502
/dev/loop12     164M  164M     0 100% /snap/spotify/41
/dev/loop13     291M  291M     0 100% /snap/vlc/1700
/dev/loop14     291M  291M     0 100% /snap/vlc/1620
/dev/loop15      63M   63M     0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1506
/dev/sda1       256M   37M  220M  15% /boot/efi
/dev/sda9        45G   22G   21G  52% /home
tmpfs           787M   40K  787M   1% /run/user/1000</pre>
```

MY largest files in the system that is above 50mb

```
51.359 MB    libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37
53.826 MB    libreoffice-common
61.150 MB    libllvm6.0
61.758 MB    libllvm9
66.071 MB    libllvm9
66.081 MB    linux-modules-5.3.0-28-generic
66.244 MB    linux-modules-5.3.0-46-generic
66.371 MB    linux-modules-5.3.0-51-generic
67.433 MB    linux-headers-5.4.0-33
67.453 MB    linux-headers-5.4.0-37
69.052 MB    linux-modules-5.4.0-29-generic
69.060 MB    linux-modules-5.4.0-28-generic
69.602 MB    linux-modules-5.4.0-31-generic
69.602 MB    linux-modules-5.4.0-33-generic
69.637 MB    linux-modules-5.4.0-37-generic
70.296 MB    libllvm10
70.706 MB    libnvidia-gl-390
70.884 MB    yaru-theme-icon
71.276 MB    libnvidia-gl-390
80.368 MB    libnvidia-compute-390
81.794 MB    libnvidia-compute-390
87.731 MB    fonts-noto-cjk
87.940 MB    nodejs
99.738 MB    snapd
122.267 MB   libreoffice-core
147.893 MB   zoom
162.652 MB   openjdk-11-jre-headless
170.113 MB   thunderbird
170.316 MB   discord
172.541 MB   linux-modules-extra-5.3.0-28-generic
172.832 MB   linux-modules-extra-5.3.0-46-generic
172.877 MB   linux-modules-extra-5.3.0-51-generic
180.665 MB   linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-33-generic
180.667 MB   linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-31-generic
180.726 MB   linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-37-generic
181.130 MB   linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-29-generic
181.160 MB   linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-28-generic
195.652 MB   firefox
216.508 MB   locales-all
224.918 MB   google-chrome-stable
243.292 MB   brave-browser
252.870 MB   code
260.271 MB   libgl1-mesa-dri
279.021 MB   libgl1-mesa-dri
284.197 MB   skypeforlinux
314.970 MB   fonts-noto-extra
510.654 MB   linux-firmware
```

My `/opt` file has about 1 GB and my `/usr` about 5.8GB and my var file is `/var` 4.2 GB

**uname -r**

`5.4.0-37-generic`

`dpkg --list | grep linux-image` give me:

```
ii  linux-image-5.4.0-37-generic               5.4.0-37.41                             amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ii  linux-image-generic                        5.4.0.37.40                             amd64        Generic Linux kernel image
ii  linux-image-unsigned-5.4.0-33-generic      5.4.0-33.37                             amd64        Linux kernel image for version 5.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
```

I listened to some guide claiming `/` only requires 15gb max. now I am messed up.
my`/home` file has a lot of space left.

Comment: The recommended minimum for Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Desktop is 25GB as space is required as you add additional software, upgrades (especially the eventual *release-upgrade* to a new version which requires lots of space as you need to download the new system, prior to install, then once everything is installed, then and only then is clean performed). I take it this is a server?   https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements though I see containerized (snap) GUI files; containerized apps require more space too; so why didn't you use the official guides?  Me I like 32gb or more..

Comment: my mistake looks like I need to go for a reinstall. or is there a way to enlarge the space?. I'm using 250gb SSD, with rest of the space covered by windows os

Comment: The space you need depends on how you will use the system (whether or not you'll *nuke & clean install* rather than *release-upgrade*; myself I prefer upgrade, but many bloggers like the nuke route which doesn't require the free space available.., & a lot of other things you yourself need to decide.. though hard if you've little experience living with it)  You can adjust space using a 'live' system ('live' so the disk isn't in use), but it can be on a running system (but it's a lot more hassle); see https://askubuntu.com/questions/116351/increase-partition-size-on-which-ubuntu-is-installed

Answer (score 1):

May be http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man1/purge-old-kernels.1.html can help you to cleanup the old kernel modules and free disk space on the root filesystem.

But if you have more disk space available on your drive, try to enlarge the partition [How to extend my root (/) partition?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/492054/how-to-extend-my-root-partition). May be it is possible to you to squeeze other partitions.

Comment: I think this would be the solution for me to go ahead and increase the size