# Ubuntu 20.04.01 LTS: Low Disk Space notification

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, 20.04, gparted

**Issue:**

Regularly receive a "*Low Disk Space on "Filesystem root"*" notification which is showing more frequently. Being relatively new to `operating systems` and `dual booting`, currently unsure of how to address this. An output of the notification:
[image]

**Information:**

Some time ago, on a new PC (a `HP-Pavilion Pro TP01-1023na Desktop`) which came with `Windows 10` already booted, the decision was made to `dual boot` with `Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS`, although perhaps not enough space was allocated when partitioning, hence the aforementioned notification.

Having installed `gparted`, this is the current output:

[image]

**Please note:** before asking this question, the following resources have been consulted which is where the idea to install and utilise `gparted` came from:

- [Low disk Space in Root Filesystem Error - ubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1252388/low-disk-space-in-root-filesystem-error-ubuntu-20-04)
- [How to extend my root (/) partition?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/492054/how-to-extend-my-root-partition)
- https://www.howtogeek.com/114503/how-to-resize-your-ubuntu-partitions/

**Question:**

**Q1.** Would it be possible for anyone to list or point me to a step-by-step guide to repartition (if this is the correct term?) so that there is more space for the `Ubuntu` boot? The `Windows` partition will likely never be used again, so I could completely get rid of this (unless it's a good idea to keep it).

Having been stuck with this query for some time, I would be highly appreciative if anyone could aid in rectifying this issue.

---

**EDIT:** Please see below an output from running `df -h /` :

[image]

Comment: Your gparted output does not help, you seem to have Ubuntu on another disk. See the dropdown list on the upper right of your screenshot. Please add output of `df -h /`.

Comment: The minimum recommended size for all Ubuntu Desktop systems from 17.10 up was 25GB (ie. since GNOME returned to the main desktop), but you have no partition of a Ubuntu capable install listed in your picture. You also say it's Ubuntu 20.04.1; which implies you've not looked at your install, or haven't applied upgrades in a year+ (https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/02/05/ubuntu-20-04-2-lts-released/ shows the ISO release date, but systems upgraded to 20.04.2 weeks before that date; an upgraded system will report as 20.04.3 currently and will soon change to 20.04.4, but not 20.04.1)

Comment: There is no "Ubuntu" on your disk. Are you running from an USB-stick ?

Comment: Thank you all for your inputs, and apologies for the delayed response. @pLumo please see my updated question with the output from `df -h /`. @guiverc I am slightly confused by this, when I run `lsb_release -a` I see `Description: Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS` ; does this mean that I have neglected to upgrade my system, and should do this immediately?

Comment: @kanehekili I booted the OS from a `USB-stick`, but no, the OS is not running from this (nor a CD etc)

Comment: Your system is well behind on upgrades (*if it's a Ubuntu system as per my prior comment*) with the fact that it reports as 20.04.1 highlighting that; or problems with your system. You should look into that (esp. if box is online!), but that is not the point of this question of yours.  One question per post/thread on this site.

Comment: Thanks @guiverc for highlighting this, I will address it in a new question.

Comment: @pLumo do you have any thoughts on the output of `df -h /` added to the question please? I unfortunately have not managed to rectify this issue yet - maybe I have to get rid of the boot entirely and start again with a newer version of Ubuntu?