# Why is ubuntu showing "DISK FULL" when I have 150GB free?

Tags: 20.04, disk-usage

I have a little problem with my disk space. Ubuntu file manager says "4.6 GB / 12.6GB Availible". 1st I have 250 GB disk, so what does that "12.6 GB availible" mean ? and 2nd When I look at Baobab (disk usage analyzer) it says that my home folder is only 65GB. SO where does that 150 GB of diskspace went ? (I have 250GB SSD)
I searched a little bit and I found that it can be set in installer, but it should be ok if I not changed anything in partitioning and let it by default. That's what I did. So it should be partiotioned as ubuntu patiotioned it.
P.S I donẗ understand how ubuntu disk partiotioning works.

Edit:
Output of df -h: https://pastebin.com/QdQTHgTY

Edit 2:
Screenshot from Disks: [image]

Comment: Could you please paste the output of `df -h` to your question. Thanks

Comment: Ubuntu uses wrong descriptions sometimes.  In this case instead of disk it should say partition.  Would open up program 'Disks' and see your partition sizes.  Then we can see if it is small partition size or an error in reporting disk size.

Comment: I read rpool. Is it zfs filesystem?

Comment: @nobody - yes, rpool is zfs member if you mean that, no if you mean partition type, it's Solaris Root

Comment: Please help !! I am really frustated of it =(  I need to do a lot of things, but my disk space doesn't allow me to easily do it..... Really please help !!!

Comment: does this reference help? https://askubuntu.com/questions/116351/increase-partition-size-on-which-ubuntu-is-installed

Comment: @User24601 Not at all, I don't know what I need, I am not sure if the problem is same as there.... I don't understand ubuntu disks much, so....  In gparted I see only one partition called /dev/sda

Comment: By the views it looks like this is pretty common, so why nobody can help me out ?

Comment: Why nobody can help me out ? Please help ===((((