# Ubuntu 22.04: Missing Disk Space

Tags: 22.04, disk-usage, disk

I have installed Ubuntu 22.04 on a home server on 1 TB SSD with other drives of 6TB as storage.
I needed some space on my SDD and noticed it is using less (approx ~ 500GB only). Looked at many suggestions and tried "resize2fs /dev/sda3" but it came up as "The filesystem is already 52428800 (4k) blocks long.  Nothing to do!" I am lost at this point to understand what to do next to recover the missing ~500GB disk space and need your help!

My Aim: looking to recover the missing space so I can make use of it.
Appreciate and thanks in advance for helping me here!

Here are the commands and outputs:

```
**root@rb:/# fdisk -l /dev/sda**
Disk /dev/sda: 931.51 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Disk model: CT1000MX500SSD1
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 06080D25-52E6-43BE-8ABD-5DCE69016631

Device         Start       End   Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sda1       2048      4095      2048    1M BIOS boot
/dev/sda2       4096   2101247   2097152    1G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda3    2101248 421531647 419430400  200G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda4  421531648 631246847 209715200  100G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda5  631246848 652218367  20971520   10G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda6  652218368 861933567 209715200  100G Linux filesystem

**root@rb:/# lsblk /dev/sda**
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
sda      8:0    0 931.5G  0 disk
├─sda1   8:1    0     1M  0 part
├─sda2   8:2    0     1G  0 part /boot
├─sda3   8:3    0   200G  0 part /
├─sda4   8:4    0   100G  0 part /var
├─sda5   8:5    0    10G  0 part /usr
└─sda6   8:6    0   100G  0 part /home

**root@rb:/# df -h** | grep -v overlay
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
tmpfs           3.2G  6.5M  3.2G   1% /run
/dev/sda3       196G  8.4G  178G   5% /
/dev/sda5       9.8G  5.1G  4.2G  55% /usr
tmpfs            16G     0   16G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs            16G     0   16G   0% /run/shm
/dev/sda4        98G  5.5G   88G   6% /var
/dev/sda2       974M  336M  571M  38% /boot
/dev/sda6        98G   24M   93G   1% /home
/dev/sdb5       4.0T  3.3T  428G  89% /export
/dev/sdb1        92G  8.0K   87G   1% /export/mnt/root
/dev/sdc        916G   72K  870G   1% /export/mnt/1tb
/dev/sdb4       1.4T  8.0K  1.3T   1% /export/mnt/home
tmpfs           3.2G  4.0K  3.2G   1% /run/user/1000
```

Comment: Thanks for looking into this. I have updated my question with output as requested.

Comment: I can see that on `/dev/sda`, you only have 410 GB out of 931 GB allocated on partitions. So you have 2 options: Either create a new partition from the remaining disk space, or resize an existing partition. See [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24027/how-can-i-resize-an-ext-root-partition-at-runtime) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/116351/increase-partition-size-on-which-ubuntu-is-installed/) for resizing partitions.

Comment: Sorry, I've cleaned out your command output, since as I understand it your question only relates to `/dev/sda`.

Comment: Thank you for your directions, Resizing was the way for me to recover the missing disk space. I used GPARTED live cd to perform the operations and was able to recover almost 2TB of disk space from across my drives. Thank you again!

Comment: how do I award points?

Comment: You upvote the relevant answers in [this Q&A](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126153/how-to-resize-partitions).