# How can I create a partition without the usage of Live CD nor USB?

Tags: mount, live-usb, live-cd, gparted

**Translation**

*Is it possible to create a partition when using the system? When I try to do it on GParted, it seems that the options are disabled because of the disk is mounted and it cannot be unmounted because of I am using it in the system.*

*I wish to create a new partition without removing or affecting the file system; just creating a new partition, but without the need to use a Live CD or USB.*

---

¿Cómo crear una partición sin usar live CD ni USB?

¿Es posible crear una partición estando en el sistema? Ya que cuando lo intento desde GParted, al parecer están desactivadas las opciones porque la unidad está montada y no se puede desmontar ya que estoy usando el sistema. Quiero crear una nueva partición pero sin quitar o afectar el sistema de archivos; sólo crear una nueva partición, pero sin live CD o USB.

Answer (score 2):

The fast answer is **NO, you can't**.

This has been discussed in the past, in questions like: [Why I'm seeing a lock besides the partition I'm trying to modify with gparted?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/51272/resize-partition-with-gparted) of which the answers provides enough information. I strongly suggest you to read it, and if you are experiencing any issues with booting a live CD/USB perform a search on this site. If the answers to previous questions doesn't fit your needs, open a new question explaining what are your live session's issues in order to obtain the proper support.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you **can** create a new partition on a drive even if some existing partitions on that drive are mounted or in use by the system. If you check the image @GeppettvsD'Constanzo linked to, you'll see that only the partitions which are currently in use (i.e. mounted) are "locked" in gparted, so nothing prevents you from removing/resizing, say `/dev/sda1` on that picture and creating a new partition.

But, as I said, you only need to modify existing partitions if you don't have enough unpartitioned space on the drive and need to resize existing partitions, all of which happen to be in use.

If you do need to resize the boot partition, it is in fact possible to do that using the low-level tools which GParted itself uses, see [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/109224/14564) (and [another one](https://askubuntu.com/a/116367/14564)) for instructions.

Another possible cause of the option to create a new partition being disabled in GParted is if you have 4 primary partitions on the drive, which is the maximum number MBR supports.