# How to increase boot partition on Ubuntu Server, via SSH?

Tags: 13.04, boot, server, 13.10

I have a Ubuntu Server currently running 13.04. I want to upgrade to 13.10 but I get an error:

```
Not enough free disk space 

The upgrade has aborted. The upgrade needs a total of 61.0 M free 
space on disk '/boot'. Please free at least an additional 21.5 M of 
disk space on '/boot'. Empty your trash and remove temporary packages 
of former installations using 'sudo apt-get clean'.
```

The boot partition is:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda5        76M   35M   38M  48% /boot
```

I have followed the various other questions to free more space. I ran the clean command above, and I have removed all old kernels so now I only have the latest kernel.

Looking around, it seems that 200MB is a recommended size for `/boot`, but the only answers I've seen say to use gparted on the LiveCD.

However, I only have SSH access to the server so this is not an option. Is there some way to repartition the hard drive over SSH?

Comment: `sudo parted /dev/sda print` will show you the start and end location of your partitions. You can check whether you have room around your /boot partition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry, but it is very likely you can't.

Resizing partitions cannot be done while the partition is in use. While your system might tolerate you unmounting `/boot` at runtime, in order to resize it, you need some free space directly after or before that partition, which in all likelyhood is taken up by your `/`, which you cannot unmount while the OS is running.

There's one chance this might work after all, but it depends on you having a swap partition adjacent to `/boot`. If that's the case, you can unmount `/boot` and disable swapping, then remove your swap partition, use that space to grow `/boot` and create a new, slightly smaller swap partition in the leftover space. Another question here on AskUbuntu has [all the details](https://askubuntu.com/questions/109215/resize-disk-partition-on-remote-vm-server) on that.

Comment: I've given some thought as to a solution to this fellow's problem.  What do you think of the following: Copy `/boot`'s contents to a new directory such as `/boot-tmp`, unmount `/boot`, remove the entry for the boot partition in `/etc/fstab`, then remove `/boot` and rename `/boot-tmp` to `/boot`.  From what I'm thinking, this should work. I might try it out on a VM and get back to this. If it does work, I'll create a separate answer post detailing it.